# Access javascript variable from another website

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

How can I access the value of a javascript variable from a website from a different website using javascript. So basically a javascript or jquery function to just get a single javascript variable from a website.

Comment: [You cannot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), and that's a good thing. (I assume that by "different website" you mean another domain that does not belong to you)

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?